# go test -run: how to specify the package in the test identifier

Tags: go, testing

Let's say I have two packages foo/bar and foo/baz. Both foo/bar and foo/baz have a TestFoo, but I only want to run foo/bar's TestFoo. Additionally, foo/baz has a TestBaz that I want to run.

Is it possible to specify a `go test` command that will run just foo/bar::TestFoo and foo/baz::TestBaz?

I've tried using `go test -run` for this, but it looks like the run regex just filters by name, not by the package identifier:

`go test -run "TestFoo|TestBaz" foo/bar foo/baz`

Ideally, I'd want to do something like:

`go test -run "foo/bar/TestFoo|foo/baz/TestBaz" foo/bar foo/baz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to specify a go test command that will run just foo/bar::TestFoo and foo/baz::TestBaz?

No, this is not possible.

(Packages normally should be self contained and testing one selected test out of several simply isn't a common use case. Testing several or all packages works good enough via go test ./...)